# How do I create a network of sites that understand single sign-on?

Tags: .net, authentication, single-sign-on

I have several sites (Asp.Net) that I would like to have a single sign on for...

I would like a user to visit Site1 and have Site1 contact a central single sign-on server (SSS).

The SSS would then determine that the user was not logged on (Not sure how) and would redirect the user to a Logon screen (Still on the SSS).

If authenticated, the user would be redirected back to Site1.

Site1 would treat this arrival as new and would likely ask the SSS if the user was logged on. This time the SSS would suggest that the user in question was indeed logged on. And so Site1 could store this fact in it's session for future reference (perhaps with some suitable timeout)

Site1 would contain a link to Site2 which the user might choose to follow.

Arrival at Site2 should trigger an attempt by Site2 to authenticate the user.

**How can I identify the user arriving on Site2 as the same user who already visited Site1 and discover that they have already been authenticated in order that they need not have to log in a second time?**

**Note: The SSS needs to be a private system where I control the account creation. So I'm afraid I can't be relying on external OpenID servers**

Update: I am unable to guarantee at this time that Site1, Site2 and SSS would be within the same domain... So I don't *think* cookies will cut it.

Comment: Is this a network of pornosites? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't discard OpenID so rapidly - as the site owner, it's up to you to choose which OpenID provider(s) you choose to support. You could choose to run your own OpenID server and only trust it.

Also, remember that OpenID is a system for authentication - how user X proves they are who they say they are.

Here on StackOverflow, they automatically create accounts when someone uses an OpenID to log on - but you don't have to do that. You can have full control over account creation, with an OpenID associated with each account.

Remember too, that (generally) any software you don't have to write and maintain is a good thing.

Comment: "You could choose to run your own OpenID server and only trust it." - ok that sounds interesting... Any suggestions where to start researching this?

Answer (score 1):

Do it the same way everyone else does it, pass around DB-generated tokens between sites with GET or POST, then validate those tokens back to a web service that talks to the DB directly.

So user wants in to site 1 (www.domain1.com). Site 1 checks local domain login session/cookie, fails to find any, redirects user to http://logindomain.com/?return=www.domain1.com. If an earlier logindomain cookie exists (from sign-ins to affiliated sites), send it back to site 1. If not, do whatever user auth you require (KERBEROS checks, Forms auth, openID, etc.) to generate a unique token. Store that in the cookie for logindomain, and redirect them back to wherever "return" pointed to, with your token attached: http://www.domain1.com/?token=123456. Once domain1 validates the token against a web service (or the token DB directly), it can set its own local login session/cookie with the user credentials.

So now you're on site 2 (www.domain2.com) and go to log in. You get redirected to logindomain again with the ?return var set, but it doesn't ask you for the password this time - it already has your token in its SSO cookie. You get immediately redirected back to: http://www.domain2.com/?token=123456 (same token as site1 used). Domain2 validates the token again, and lets you in with no password check.

It gets a little more complicated if you're changing the login URL on the fly or trying to make a hybrid AD/Forms Auth monster like I was tasked to build, but this seems to work fine and matches exactly (at a high level) what IBM and MS docs say their proprietary SSO systems do.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a shared session state server.

Comment: That sounds interesting... But what piece of unique information can I have Site1 and Site2 pass to said server in order that they both present the user as the same person

Answer (score 0):

You could use cookies to store and create authentication tickets for users. We've done that several times and it's worked out quite well.

Comment: I thought that cookies were domain specific. Site1, Site2 and SSS *might* be at differing domains and therefore not capable of reading each others cookies?

Comment: Well, here is how we handled it. We have a primary sign on site, we'll call it site1, site1 has links to site2, when you follow said links, site1 performs a post to that page with the username to a authentication form on site2 which then creates the ticket. Sorry, forgot we didn't usecookie on that.

Comment: Basically, site1 becomes your SSO solution and handles the authentication to site2, though if you visit site2 first, you'd need to have it redirect to the site that handles your authentication, not a big deal really.